# Issue with binary tree creation from array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, recursion, binary-tree

I am having trouble working with a recursive function that builds a binary tree.

```
tree_link tree_from_array_preorder(Item arr[], int N) 
{   
    int pos =0;
    int * pos_ptr=&pos;
    //struct tree_struct treeOfLife;
    if((N<1)|| (arr[0]==0))
        return NULL;

    tree_link root=new_tree_link(arr[pos]);
    root->left=tree_from_array_preorder_aux(arr, pos_ptr, N);
    root->right=tree_from_array_preorder_aux(arr, pos_ptr, N);
    return root;
}

tree_link   tree_from_array_preorder_aux(Item arr[], int *pos, int N) 
{
    if(arr[pos]==0)
        return NULL;
    tree_link root= new_tree_link(arr[pos]);
    (pos)+=1;
    root->left=tree_from_array_preorder_aux(arr, pos, N);
    root->right=tree_from_array_preorder_aux(arr, pos, N);
    return root;

}
```

I keep getting errors about conflicting types between the aux function and my call to it. I'm pretty sure I have my pointer declaration messed up somewhere, and my reference to said pointer as well. Any help would be appreciates and thank you for your time.

Comment: is a binary search tree? right?

Comment: Do you declare a prototype for the `aux` function above `tree_from_array_preorder`? What is the exact error text?

Comment: actually I just got it working. I forgot to declare the prototype in the added .h header file I use for this program. Thank you for answering though, Always found comments to help more than they hurt here.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to declare the prototype in the added .h header file I use for this program. … – JustaRedShirt